# Access a XML file via xslt which is present two level below xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

location of properties.xml -> web-inf/classes

location of XSLT           -> web-inf/classes/xslt/req/Request.xslt

Properties.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Properties>
       <UserId>abc</UserId>
       <Password>password</Password>
     </Properties>
```

XSLT File :

```
       <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
         <xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Envelope 
             xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
             xmlns:abc="urn:microsoft-dynamics-
             schemas/codeunit/abc_WebService" 
             xmlns:any="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/Any">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <abc:ImportabcXML>
                <abc:requestXML>                         
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </abc:requestXML>
                <abc:userId><xsl:value-of select="document('/Properties.xml')/Properties/UserId"/></abc:userId>
                <abc:password><xsl:value-of select="document('/Properties.xml')/Properties/Password"/></abc:password>
            </abc:ImportabcXML>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>      
</xsl:template>
```

I am not able to access the userid and password fields in XML properties file in output I am getting only :

```
   Current output :
   ....</abc:userId></abc:password>....

    Expected output :
   ....<abc:userId>abc</abc:userId><abc:password>password</abc:password>...
```

**What changes I have to make to document tag so that I can access attributes of Properties.xml present in folder two level below XSLT file?**

What I read in one link is location of file to be used by XSLT file should be at same folder level of XSLT. So how can I access the file which is present one level below XSL folder.

Edit : changed one level to two as indicated by Michael.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I access the file which is present one level below XSL folder.

If your stylesheet is located at:

```
web-inf/classes/xslt/req/Request.xslt
```

and the `Properties` file is at:

```
web-inf/classes/Properties.xml
```

then it is not "one level below" but two levels above - and should be accessible using:

```
document('../../Properties.xml')
```

---

Note that XML is case-sensitive: `properties.xml` is not the same as `Properties.xml`.

Comment: Thank Michael for answer. But still I am getting sane output   ...</abc:userId></abc:password>.... Is there any other problem in code which is preventing to get output :<abc:userId>abc</abc:userId><abc:password>password</abc:password>.

Comment: Not that I can see.